# sonarQube wrapper stopped

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I just started learning SonarQube, but the first level faces this error:
(on windows 10 - 64 bit)

```
 D:\sesn\sonarqube-6.7.5\bin\windows-x86-64>StartSonar.bat
    wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
    wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
    jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
    jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
    jvm 1    |
    jvm 1    | 2018.11.14 15:59:05 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory D:\sesn\sonarqube-6.7.5\temp
    jvm 1    | 2018.11.14 15:59:05 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
    jvm 1    | 2018.11.14 15:59:05 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [D:\sesn\sonarqube-6.7.5\elasticsearch]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\java -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -server -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Djdk.io.permissionsUseCanonicalPath=true -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0 -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true -Dlog4j.skipJansi=true -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Delasticsearch -Des.path.home=D:\sesn\sonarqube-6.7.5\elasticsearch -cp lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch -Epath.conf=D:\sesn\sonarqube-6.7.5\temp\conf\es
    jvm 1    | 2018.11.14 15:59:06 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
    jvm 1    | 2018.11.14 15:59:06 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
    jvm 1    | 2018.11.14 15:59:06 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
    jvm 1    | 2018.11.14 15:59:21 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is up
    jvm 1    | 2018.11.14 15:59:21 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='web', ipcIndex=2, logFilenamePrefix=web]] from [D:\sesn\sonarqube-6.7.5]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\sesn\sonarqube-6.7.5\temp -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/server/*;D:\sesn\sonarqube-6.7.5\lib\jdbc\h2\h2-1.3.176.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer D:\sesn\sonarqube-6.7.5\temp\sq-process1230061572006055077properties
    jvm 1    | 2018.11.14 15:59:23 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [web] is stopped
    jvm 1    | 2018.11.14 15:59:23 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
    jvm 1    | 2018.11.14 15:59:23 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
    wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

I used 32-bit version but got the same error. I searched through net and solution did not work. What should I do? tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but the problem was because I had JetBrains PhpStrom running int he background. As I closed it, the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Web server of SonarQube fails to start:

> Process [web] is stopped

I recommend you to have a look in /logs/web.log.
You should have more information about the root cause of your problem there.